# Redirect certain domain to personal domain via dns

Tags: networking, dns, domain

I'm trying to redirect all traffic requests from a domain that I don't own to another one that I do via dns.  But Acrylic can only forward to an IP, not a domain.  Is there any way I can do it using Acrylic or is there some other program I can use?  No, I can't just forward directly to my domain's IP because it's dynamic. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So you are not looking at redirection as such (as that happens at the
>   app level ie on apache/nginx/wherever) but rather on the DNS
>   resolution - host on which DomainA is hosted will or should never be
>   hit - based on your description as you want the DNS requests to be
>   resolved to the IPs of the DomainB. Unless I'm missing something in
>   your request ?
>
> As Shane pointed out DNS is not capable of HTTP redirection - that's
>   an application/webserver duty. You could make DomainA and DomainB
>   resolve to the same IP on DNS and all would work.But if you're looking
>   to do this on per URL/per-path way then this is not possible - DNS is
>   not capable of that - it's a simple DNS->IP service, what's happening
>   with the actual URL is the webserver's task.
>
> Ok, so after the comment below...what I'd do is to refer all DNS
>   records for DomainA to the same IP(s) as DomainB is pointed to - this
>   way you will get HTTP request hitting hostB and then it's just a
>   simple matter of:
>
> - A) creating a particular apache Name Baseed Virtual host - which will be serving files from its own DocumentRoot
> - B) creating permanent redirect on apache like this: This will rewrite anything coming to DomainB to DomainA which can be hosted on
>     the same server or somewhere else. I appreciate that the second option
>     is probably an overhead and not necessary if you can/are allowed to
>     create Name Based Virtual hosts on apache.
>
> `<VirtualHost *:80>   ServerName DomainB   Redirect permanent /
>   http://DomainA/ </VirtualHost>`
>
> I'd go with a) - point all DNS records of DomainA to the same IP(s) as
>   DomainB is pointing and create particular Name Based VirtualHosts on
>   apache

Source: [similar question on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/385893/how-to-redirect-domain-a-to-domain-b-using-a-records-and-cname-records-only)